# Entity Framework : include only one row of each reference id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to include only the first row of `Comments` for each `BlogPost`. How I can do that?

This code here includes every comment:

```
var query = _inventoryContext.BlogPosts
                             .Include(x => x.Comments)
                             .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: ```var first = _inventoryContext.BlogPosts.Include(x => x.Comments).AsQueryable().First();```

Comment: `.Include(x => x.Comments.OrderBy(...).Take(1))` ?

Comment: Exploding Kitten... That's what I tried already, got this error.

System.ArgumentException: 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: Specify EF version. Looks like you are using EF which do not support [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)

Comment: EF version 6.0.0.0

Comment: Then you can't do that via `Include`, But you can project via `Select`.